# Dividend yield for multiple years?

Tags: stock-analysis, dividends, stock-dividend, italy

I am looking for an indicator of percentage of dividend stocks about last 5 (?) years.

It is easy to find info about dividend of last year ([Dividend_yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_yield) but I cannot find an indicator for multiple years)

I woul like to use his indicator to compare stocks exchanged on **italian market** before buying any of them, so I have no strarting price for any stocks

Comment: For a specific stock?

Comment: @AustinFrench no, I need it to use for my personal analysis for stocks I consider interesting

Comment: @Ale, just look up the dividend history of the company...

Comment: @quid I can easily find the dividend quote for past years, but it is long to check the quote for the day of the dividend payment

Answer (score 1):

I've recently discovered that Morningstar provides 5yr avgs of a few numbers, including dividend yield, for free.  For example, see the right-hand column in the 'Current Valuation' section, 5th row down for the 5yr avg dividend yield for PG:

http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/price-ratio.html?t=PG&region=usa&culture=en-US

Another site that probably has this, and alot more, is YCharts.  But that is a membership site so you'll need to join (and pay a membership fee I believe.)   YCharts is supposedly pretty good for long-term statistical information and trend graphs for comparing and tracking stocks.

Comment: This should be what I am looking for, but italian version of morningstar seems do not have those info

Comment: You should add a country tag to your question to say you're specifically looking for Italian stocks then.  If that's not the stocks you're looking for, then your issue is simply how to get to non-Italian versions of sites, for which I'd recommend a VPN if the site doesn't offer such an option itself.

Answer (score 1):

Dividend yield is a tough thing to track because it's a moving target.  Dividends are paid periodically the yield is calculated based on the stock price when the dividend is declared (usually, though some services may update this more frequently).

I like to calculate my own dividend by annualizing the dividend payment divided by my cost basis per share.  As an example, say you have shares in X, Co.  X issues a quarterly dividend of $1 per share and the share price is $100; coincidentally this is the price at which you purchased your shares.

```
$1 x 4 = $4 (times four because quarterly of quarterly frequency)
$4 / $100 = 4%
```

But a few years goes by and now X issues it's quarterly dividend of $1.50 per share, and the share price is $160.

```
$1.50 x 4 = $6
$6 / $160 = 3.75%
```

However your shares only cost you $100.

```
$1.50 x 4 = $6
$6 / $100 = 6%
```

Your annual yield on X is 6%, not the published 3.75%.  All of this is to say that looking back on dividend yields is somewhat similar to nailing jello to the wall.  Do you look at actual dividends paid through the year divided by share price?  Do you look at the annualized dividend at the time of issue then average those?  The stock price will fluctuate, that will change the yield; depending on where you bought your stock, your actual yield will vary from the published amount as well.

Comment: This is an interesting notice. I would like to calculate dividend yield indipendelty on the price bought (because this is an element that I would like to study BEFORE the buying action, so I do not any starting price). I will edit the question

Comment: Sites that generated the number the OP is asking for should be calculating the 5yr Avg Yield by averaging the values found by taking the annual dividend (either TTM, or current div annualized like your doing) and dividing it by the days closing price, summed over every trading day of the 5 years.   What you're doing is not the same thing.  Your calculating YoC (Yield on Cost).